# Some functions inside `Task` closure becomes an async function in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, asynchronous, task

I'm not sure how is this being triggered, but *sometimes* when I call a function inside `Task { }` XCode gives an error that instructs me to add `await` in the called function.

Here's a simplified instance I experienced:

```
public class Loader: UIView {
   

   
    public class func show(animated: Bool = true) {
        // showing the loader code
    }
}

enum Utilities {
    func doSomeAsyncTask(action: @escaping ()async->()) {
        Task {
            Loader.show() // XCode error: "Expression is 'async' but is not marked with 'await'"
            action()
        }      
    }
}
```

XCode shows the function is an async one

Does this have something to do that this is a class or something?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIView` is marked with the global actor `@MainActor`. Since `Loader` inherits from `UIView`, `Loader` is implicitly marked with `@MainActor` too.

This means that all the methods in `Loader` are isolated to the `MainActor`. The things in `Task { ... }` are not isolated to the `MainActor`. Therefore, to run a `MainActor`-isolated method in `Task { ... }`, you need to `await` for it. `MainActor` could be busy with something else at that time, and you'd need to wait for a bit before it runs `show`.

The methods that do not become `async` when you put them in `Task { ... }` are probably not isolated to a particular actor, e.g.

```
// not actor-isolated
func square(_ x: Int) -> Int { x * x }

enum Utilities {
    func doSomeAsyncTask(action: @escaping ()async->()) {
        Task {
            print(square(4)) // doesn't need async
            await action()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a very clear explanation. Big thanks!